# Starting app in background when beaconmanager is bound

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon, beacon

I have trouble with showing my app on region entered, I followed the sample [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).
It works when I don't `bind` the BeaconManager to my Activty, but when I do, I get the logs from the Activity not from the Application and the app doesn't show up although it's not visible.

So the question is, can I use a class `extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier` for starting the app in background and a class `extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer` to handle monitoring/ranging or do I need to handle everything in the application class because binding it in the activity fails the background launch?

(Sorry for the bad code block, I just can't handle this stackoverflow code thing correctly)

```
    public class BeaconActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

    protected final String TAG = "BeaconActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       RangedBeacon.setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(8000);
       beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
       beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Unbind Beaconmanager");
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(final Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Enter Region identifier: " + region.getId1() + ", " + region.getId2() + ", " + region.getId3());
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(final Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exit Region identifier: " + region.getId1() + ", " + region.getId2() + ", " + region.getId3());
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {

            }
        });

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                for (final Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    final String distance = new DecimalFormat("##.######").format(beacon.getDistance());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Distance: " + distance + ". This beacon has identifiers:" + beacon.getId1() + ", " + beacon.getId2() + ", " + beacon.getId3());
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            Region region = new Region("all", null, null, null);
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(all);
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(all);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }
}



public class BeaconApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {

        private static final String TAG = "BeaconApplication";
        private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
            BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                    setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

            Region all = new Region("all", null, null, null);
            regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, all);
        }

        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Enter region " + region.getUniqueId());
    //        regionBootstrap.disable();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeaconActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exit region " + region.getUniqueId());
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
I think I might just screwed up a little. Explained [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html) the app only launches if killed (not in task switcher anymore). If it's available in task switcher it just handles the incoming events in the background, that's why I get the activity logs.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "because binding it in the activity fails the background launch"?

Comment: I thought if i call `beaconManager.bind(this);` in BeaconActivity the background launches from BeaconApplication dont work anymore. But I think I know why now (see edit). Can you confirm that binding the beaconmanager to the activity doesn't affect the application class at all?

Comment: It should not affect the application class, no.  That is how the RangingActivity works in the reference app:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/RangingActivity.java

Comment: And to clarify, the app should not only launch if not in the task switcher anymore.  The scanning service will keep running, and entry/exit callbacks should keep coming to the Application class.   I would check to see if you see your debug lines in didEnterRegion and didExitRegion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can only have *one* `monitorNotifier` for your application.  The `RegionBootstrap` class sets one internally, and uses it to get callbacks to your `Application` class.

The code shown above changes the `monitorNotifier` here:

```
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
...
```

After that line executes, the `RegionBootstrap` won't get any more callbacks on entry/exit events, and nor will the `Application` class.  So the problem isn't the `bind()` call, it's the `setMonitorNotifier` call.

The library does not allow multiple `monitorNotifiers`, so if you want to keep using the `RegionBootstrap` you have to refactor your code so that you get all of the entry/exit events in your Application class and somehow pass them off to your `Activity`.

Comment: Okay, problem now is that i don't get exit region calls (in application class). Only when I kill the app in task switcher the exit region triggers. The ranging in the BeaconActivity doesnt work since I added the application class too. Is there also only one `rangingNotifier` allowed? Though the activity is visible, do i need to set the scan times faster? I really struggle to combine the first samples (monitoring/ranging in one activity) and then add the background launch example. But I guess the main problem was answered.

Comment: Yes, the `BeaconManager` is a singleton so there is only one  ranging notifier active at any given time.  I recommend using the `BackgroundPowerSaver` in your Application class to set scan intervals automatically as you move from background to foreground and not call methods to set the background mode directly.